# RegExp to remove all starting numbers of new lines

Tags: regex, go

I have a text file imported as a string where some lines have included line numbers. I'm trying to remove them.

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`^\s*\d{1,}(.*)$`)
fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(inputtext, ""))
```

It seems to match fine on regex101.com but when I run it in go it does nothing.

I'm running go on Windows.

Comment: Should it match at the start of a line? Try ``"`(?m)^\s*\d{1,}(.*)$`"`` (without the `"`s)

Comment: If you've to strip-off numbers only, then you should substitute with `$1`, like - `fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(inputtext, "$1"))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that was an improvement! But it also removed everything else on the line, not just the line number. (lines where there were no line numbers were left untouched)

Comment: So you just want `(?m)^[\p{Zs}\t]*\d+`?

Comment: @vrintle that worked great! Now I just need to understand why. Thank you!

Comment: See the explanations below.

Comment: see [capturing-groups](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```golang
(?m)^[\p{Zs}\t]*\d+
```

**Details**:

- `(?m)` -  multiline mode on
- `^` -  start of a line
- `[\p{Zs}\t]*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `\d+` - one or more digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xDzqMR/1).